# Aluminium electrolytic capacitor information, top marking 9h - 100 - ELA

Tags: capacitor, identification

I'm looking for information on this SMD aluminium capacitor:

[image: photo of SMD capacitor]

On top of this one : 9h - 100 - ELA

What is the equivalence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely its a 100 uF 25 volt type

[image]

- The "LA" part may be the manufacturer's series ID number
- The "9h" may be some form of data code or lot number.

See also this variant that says roughly the same: -

[image]

Image from [here](http://m.circuitboardchips.com/quality-7992162d-aluminum-smd-electrolytic-capacitor-rohs-directive-compliant-eeefk1e471p).