# How to identify surface mount electrolytic capacitors?

Tags: identification, surface-mount, electrolytic-capacitor

Various surface mount electrolytic capacitors seem to have no consistent marking method. Here are some examples:

[image: 6V 10 35F electrolytic cap marking]
[image: 228 PC 330 4 electrolytic cap marking]
[image: 9h 100 ELA electrolytic cap marking]

<sup>(Image sources: [1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/700692/2028), [2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/546098/2028), [3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/500183/2028))</sup>

How can I identify what value and voltage rating these are?

Answer (score 6):

There is no standard with which aluminum electrolytic surface mount capacitors are marked. Each manufacturer has their own method, so you would need to look through several manufacturer datasheets to see if the marking style matches the sample that you have.

You may be able to narrow things down by taking diameter and height measurements and using electronics vendor part searches to isolate manufacturers that produce that form factor. However, as manufacturers evolve and merge or components change or are no longer manufactured, this may have limited utility.

Here are some marking examples from the datasheets of popular manufacturers of these components. Markings will vary by series and vintage, but this may be of help if a given marking style is close enough to the sample to help narrow the search.

## Nichicon

> [image: Nichicon top mark example]

## Panasonic (2 examples)

> [image: Panasonic top mark example]
> [image: Panasonic top mark example 2]

## Kemet

> [image: Kemet top mark example]

## Nippon Chemi-con

> [image: Nippon Chemi-con top mark example]

## Rubycon

> [image: Rubycon top mark example]

## Cornell Dubilier

> [image: Cornell Dubilier top mark example]

## Kyocera

> [image: Kyocera top mark example]

## Würth Elektronik

> [image: Würth top mark example]
> [image: Würth top mark explanation]

## Su'scon

> [image: Su=scon top mark example]

*Image sources are from various randomly-selected datasheets for each manufacturer.*

This is not an exhaustive list nor is it specifically identifying any of the examples in the question. The intent is to illustrate that the markings are manufacturer-dependent, but provide a few examples to illustrate the point and perhaps allow you to identify potential manufacturers, should the sample be similar enough to an example.

Comment: +1 For the answer. Since there's different markings, are there ways to identify manufacturers? (Answer is likely no but I could be wrong)

Comment: @C__ Sometimes you will see manufacturer logos. A good example of this is Würth Elektronik. Unfortunately, this seems to be the exception.